# Calculate VAT per product in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=a887be4bab160b3f1db7ed9a9e14bcc3)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    event_date DATE,
    product_name VARCHAR(255),
    sales_volume VARCHAR(255),
    vat VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(event_date, product_name, sales_volume, vat)
VALUES 
('2020-01-15', 'Product_A', '400', '0.15'),
('2020-03-20', 'Product_A', '600', '0.15'),
('2020-06-13', 'Product_A', '300', '0.19'),

('2020-05-31', 'Product_B', '200', '0.19'),
('2020-06-23', 'Product_B', '900', '0.15'),
('2020-08-02', 'Product_B', '700', '0.19'),
('2020-12-19', 'Product_B', '500', '0.19');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date    product_name      sales_volume      vat      net_sales
2020-01-15    Product_A             400          1.15      347.82608695652175
2020-03-20    Product_A             600          1.15      521.7391304347826
2020-05-31    Product_B             200          1.18      169.49152542372883
2020-06-13    Product_A             300          1.18      254.23728813559325
2020-06-23    Product_B             900          1.15      782.608695652174
2020-08-02    Product_B             700          1.18      593.2203389830509
2020-12-19    Product_B             500          1.18      423.7288135593221
```

---

In `MariaDB` I got the expected results above using this query:

```
SELECT
event_date,
product_name,
sales_volume,

(CASE WHEN vat = 0.19
THEN 1.18 ELSE (1+vat) END) AS vat,

(CASE WHEN vat = 0.19
THEN sales_volume/1.18 ELSE sales_volume/(1+vat) END) AS net_sales

FROM sales
GROUP BY 1;
```

---

Now I switched to `Postgres 9.5` and I get the below error for the query:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = numeric LINE 6:
> (CASE WHEN vat = 0.19

> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

I have no clue what I need to modify in my query to make it work. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Fix your data model so `vat` is stored as a number, not a string.

Comment: As said by Gordon, you need to change vat to a numeric type and sales_volume too...Ex.: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=52609b093966503c043a447ac20b29e5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=82c606e564cb05a631e05b9cf4af8d69)

1. Your columns vat and sales_volumn are of type `varchar(255)` which is a text type. You should convert it into a number type like `numeric` or `decimal` (alternatively you have to cast the values into such type on every usage (`CASE WHEN vat::numeric = 0.19 ...`), which is strictly not recommended)
2. Remove the `GROUP BY 1` line, since you are not doing any aggregation in your query.